# Get available X11 video modes without extensions

Tags: x11, resolution, screen-resolution

I've been searching around and can't find a solution for this.  The official NVIDIA Tegra 2 Linux SDK (L4T) doesn't include both XRandR or the VideoMode X11 extension for querying available video modes.  My next thought was to parse the log file for video modes. Of course most of the time it's at /var/log/Xorg.0.log but I'd rather not always make that assumption.  The XF86misc extension provides a way to get the log path but that extension is also not installed by default.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows of any other way to figure out what video modes are available and also what the current video mode of the display is.

Comment: NVIDIA was never a fan of XRandR...

Answer (score 1):

The core X protocol does not mention modes.  You have to use extensions.  There's nothing wrong with that, that's what extensions are for.

Also, remember that there's no guarantee that the machine you're displaying on is the same machine as you're running on, so parsing the X log file is destined to fail if your app ever runs across the network.